# Working with for but not with $.each

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, for-loop

So Im trying to populate a map in javascript like this

```
 { showOnLoad: places ....
```

And it gets the job done with a for loop like this (it does show the markers) THIS WORKS

```
  var places = [];
  for(var x= 0; x<10; x++){
    places[x] = {
        canEdit: false,
        lat: 53.79+x,
        lng:-1.5426760000000286+x,
        name: "Somewhere "+x

    }
}
```

But when I try to populate it with the info I receive on JSON/PHP from anothe page, it does not work, and it does not populate with markers...

```
var places = [];
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
var x = 0;
$.each(data.lugar, function(i,user){
    places[x] = {
        canEdit: false,
        lat: user.latt,
        lng: user.lng,
        name: user.name
        }

        x++;
    });
});
```

Even though I try to do it like that, it does not show anything, even tho if I dont use my variables it does not work... Like this

```
var places = [];
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
var x = 0;
$.each(data.lugar, function(i,user){
    places[x] = {
        canEdit: false,
        lat: 53.79+x,
        lng:-1.5426760000000286+x,
        name: "Somewhere "+x
        }

        x++;
    });
});
```

I get nothing, I dont know if Im missing out on something. I am running out of ideas on this one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You realize that the results from your `$.getJSON()` call won't be available immediately, right? If you try to examine the "places" array immediately after the `$.getJSON()` it will be empty.

Comment: What's the JSON you are receiving from the service?

Comment: I didnt know that, but Ive used promise().done(function () but I still dont get anything, I dont know if something else needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `x` is not in the variable scope of `$.each()`'s callback function.  Instead, why don't you just rely on the `i` index set in parameter one of your callback:

```
$.each(data.lugar, function(i, user) {
    places[i] = {
        canEdit: false,
        lat: user.latt,
        lng: user.lng,
        name: user.name
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait that the `each` function have proceed all results before using your array :

```
var places = [];
$.when(
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var x = 0;
    $.each(data, function (i, user) {
        places[x] = {
            canEdit: false,
            lat: user.latt,
            lng: user.lng,
            name: user.name
        };
        x++;
    });
})).done(function () {
    //Here the array "places" is ready to be used
    alert('Hey!');
});
```

Comment: Ive tried your solution but I dont know if I am missing something else because I get no display after using it, I get nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have error? Check console (F12)

Comment: Yes, I got an error, it seems to be right on that new added line. You can see the error right here http://s28.postimg.org/tpgv9n2gt/Captura.png
I dont know but it is also pointing to the JQuery library :S

Comment: @EnriqueBravo Ok, in this case, you cannot use ´promise´ like I thought, but ´when´ method. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @EnriqueBravo Still not working with this new version?